# Why extra space on right side of footer?

Tags: css

On [this site](https://www.workwave.com/fleet), if you view in under 1024px wide screen (ideally use Chrome's mobile viewer for iPhone 5 or 6), there is white space on the right side of the footer and I can't figure out how to get rid of it (i.e make the green fill up the full space), without screwing up stuff above it.

Any ideas on which CSS can be altered/added to fix this would be super appreciated.

Comment: Checked in chrome and on phone, not seeing any whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the scrollbar's silhouette. Your content's overflowing the `footer`:

Adding the following will remedy the issue:

```
.t3-wrapper { overflow-y:hidden; }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Both of these solutions work, is one better than the other for any reason? or is it a "doesn't matter either way" situation?

Comment: `overflow-y` is what's pertinent here. the content is overflowing the container vertically ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule on the `body` tag for `overflow-x:hidden !important` -- all you need to do is put the same rule on the `html` tag. Like so:

```
html,body{width:100%;overflow-x:hidden !important;}
```

Cheers!